# how exclude a specific value in css

Tags: css

I'd like to exclude all (html) elements that don't have "lang" attribute set as "en".
I know that there is :not (pseudo-element),
but if I set
    `body[lang=en] span:not([lang=en]) {display: none;}`
I get as result to made invisible *all span* elements (regardless they have or not lang attribute) that don't have "lang=en", therefore not only <span lang="de">, but also <span class="myclass">.
Il would be possible exclude *only* element that *have lang* attribute - different from "en"?

Comment: Please provide a proper [mre] of your issue, not just a one-line snippet of CSS.

Comment: `span[lang]:not([lang="en"]){display:none;}` looks like what you need . it filters every span that has a lang attribute, then excludes the ones that has a lang attribute with a value equal to *en* .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> from comment
>
> `span[lang]:not([lang="en"]){display:none;}` looks like what you need .
>   It filters every span that has a lang attribute, then excludes the ones that has a lang attribute with a value equal to en .

```css
span[lang]:not([lang="en"]) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<span lang="de">Deutch</span><br>
<span class="myclass">myclass 'n no lang</span><br>
<span lang="en">English</span>
```

This works for span , `[lang]:not([lang="en"])` will work for any element if the selector specifty is high enough. be carefull, if body has another language than en , nothing will be shown.

Comment: Pefect! Thanks. Even best is this:   
    `body[lang=en] *[lang]:not([lang="en"]){display:none;}`  
for every element (non only for "span".

Answer (score 1):

You can first make sure that they have the `[lang]` attribute and then target the non-English one only with...

```
span[lang]:not([lang="en"])
```

```css
span {
  display: block;
  padding:1em;
}

span[lang]:not([lang="en"]) {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<span lang="en">English</span>

<span lang="de">German</span>

<span>Raw span</span>
```

Comment: thank you, but is your answer different from what G-Cirillus wrote?

Comment: No but I wrote mine before he did but only by 30 seconds